# 3d scatterplot javascript or SVG

Tags: javascript, 3d, svg

i am new to this forum. At the moment i search for a 3d Scatterplot engine / library for java script or SVG. Like this:

[image]

It is importent that you can rotate it to observe the point cloud. A nice feature would be to define a color for each point.

Answer (score 1):

SVG is a graphics format you can use for rendering the plot. To calculate your plot you need Javascript. You create the plot by generating SVG with Javascript, don't mix this up… There is also the `<canvas>` tag that provides a drawing context, it could make a better performance if you have very much points to show.

Perhaps [three.js](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/) or [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) can help you to implement this. There are also a lot Javascript chart libraries out there maybe there is one the exactly does what you want.

good luck…

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Now, April 2013 and we have one

From here : http://dexvis.com/vis/blog/2013/apr/dc3/examples/ScatterPlot3D1.html

it is implemented using d3js and Three.js and really smooth altough it is just a prototype.

Check it out!

Comment: That link appears to be broken.

Comment: The site appears to be at http://dexvis.net/ and not http://dexvis.com/, so the correct link is at: http://dexvis.net/vis/blog/2013/apr/dc3/examples/ScatterPlot3D1.html

It's also worth noting that the page does not render properly if you visit the page over https://

Answer (score 1):

You can visit Javascript library [LightingchartJS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js/).
It’s been built with WebGL, so GPU assists in the rendering better than in typical HTML5/Canvas based chart libraries.
It provide interactive example for [3D scatter chart](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0900-3dScatter.html) with more than 4800 data points with great performance with rotate camera angle.

[image]

For more information you can check out our [interactive examples](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/) as well.

Full disclosure: I am a developer for LightningChart, I think you may find this very useful.